# Can you use pre-defined Action<T> in Control.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, delegates

I have some threading checks and I can get the below working by calling `BeginInvoke(new Action<string,string>........` but I was wondering if you can use pre-defined Actions somehow?

```
private Action<string, string> DoSomething();

private void MakeItHappen(string InputA, string InputB)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.BeginInvoke(DoSomething(InputA, InputB));
  }
  else
  {
     Label.Text = "Done";
     MyOtherGUIItem.Visible = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: What does "predefined action" mean?

Comment: The fact that its pre-defined as a private field instead of doing new Action<string,string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a plain `delegate` to `BeginInvoke`. You can use variable capture to wrap up your parameters like this:

```
private void MakeItHappen(string InputA, string InputB)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate () { 
            MakeItHappen(InputA, InputB); 
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff with InputA and InputB
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but how does it know how to come back into the MakeItHappen method after its put on the correct thread?

Comment: The line `private Action<string, string> DoSomething;` will not compile.

Comment: Execution does not come back into `MakeItHappen`. The delegate that you pass to `BeginInvoke` is just executed asynchronously on the UI thread.

Comment: Because the `Action` class can only take one type parameter.

Comment: @Tudor My compiler likes it. It is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx

Comment: So I would still have to point DoSomething to MakeItHappen? I've amended my question to show in code that I want to do something to controls for example

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I was accidentally targeting .NET 2.0. Apologies.

Comment: @Jon If that's what you want then there's no need for a delegate. I've updated code to match your latest comments.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this what you mean?

```
private Action<string, string> _DoSomething;

public void ConfigureToSecondThanFirstByExistingFunction()
{
    _DoSomething = MyMakeItLowerImplementation;
}

public void ConfigureToFirstThenSecondByLambda()
{
    _DoSomething = (a, b) => Console.WriteLine(a + b);
}

public void CallMe()
{
    ConfigureToSecondThanFirstByExistingFunction();
    //ConfigureToFirstThenSecondByLambda();

    _DoSomething("first", "second");
}

private void MyMakeItLowerImplementation(string a, string b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b + a);
}
```

Comment: I think he wants a method with two string parameters and no return value. The `Func` define here is a method with one string parameter and a string result.

Comment: @Tudor: yes, but the concept stays the same. I simple rewrote it now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want something like this?

```
private delegate void updateDelegate(string p1, string p2);
private updateDelegate DoSomething;

private void MakeItHappen(string InputA, string InputB)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(DoSomething, InputA, InputB);
    }
    else
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but how does it know how to come back into the MakeItHappen method after its put on the correct thread?

Comment: The call to `BeginInvoke` is non-blocking. After the method is queued to the GUI thread the call returns immediately to the `MakeItHappen` method.

Comment: I've updated my question to show I want to modify some controls after the BeginInvoke

Comment: @Jon, now I understand. Unfortunately you cannot make `DoSomething` point to `MakeItHappen` when you declare it because it requires the method to be static, so you cannot use `this`. Why is `this.BeginInvoke(new Action...);` not acceptable?

Comment: It is, I just thought if I have a set of pre-defined Actions I can use them all over the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

This way?:

```
private delegate void DoSomethingHandler(string A, string B);
private event DoSomethingHandler DoSomething;

public void Start()
{
   DoSomething = (a, b) => { /*doStuff*/ };
}

private void MakeItHappen(string InputA, string InputB)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.BeginInvoke(DoSomething, InputA, InputB);
  }
  else
  {
    //Do stuff
  }    
}
```

Comment: Ok, i see, then you need a delegate

Comment: Sorry, I was accidentally targeting .NET 2.0. In 4.0 it compiles.